# What resources causes the number of displays limitation?

Tags: gpu

Every pre-Ice Lake Intel GPU can only drive three displays. I wonder what resource shortage causes that and whether it's possible to work around that in software. Here are a few things which are not explanations:

1. Number of connectors. The same quad port MST hub that runs four 1920 x 1080 @ 60 Hz monitors with an nVidia or AMD GPU won't run four with Intel. And this requires only one DP 1.2 connector on the host.
2. The number of pixels / display bandwidth. Even if a laptop has a 4K display, two external monitors can still be added. (Coincidentally 4K is the exact same amount of pixels as four FHD displays.)

So ... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All GPUs have a piece of hardware that is essentially a bunch of counters (horizontal and vertical position), that read out the framebuffer, determine the color at this point and send it on for further processing.

You can trace the ancestry for that from the venerable [Motorola 6845](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6845) over CGA, Hercules, EGA; then earlier Intel GPUs like the i9xx family, and so on.

Some manufacturer (NVidia) still call this CRTC (Cathode-Ray Tube Controller), because that's what they originally were. Some call it "heads".

Intel calls them "Pipes". You can find details about what registers are used to control them in datasheets for earlier Intel GPUs.

So the number of these determine how many *different* images you can produce from the framebuffer. (There are other restrictions, like timing).

Though it's possible (at least for most Intel GPUs) to use a single pipe to drive multiple displays, with the same image ("mirroring"). This is also called "Zaphod-Mode" (multiple heads).

References:

A list of Intel graphics hardware specification can be found [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/hardware-specification-prms). In particular, the Volume 3 of the [i965 programmer's manual](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/965_g35_vol_3_display_registers_updated.pdf) explains the Display Pipeline ("Pipe") registers in section 2.7. In section 2.5, the PLL (phase-locked loop) registers responsible for the timing are described; if you understand the details, you know why some of the timing constraints are there.

That's the earliest public manuals I know that describe this architecture.

The source code for the Linux kernel Intel graphics driver can be found [here](https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-xf86-video-intel). You can see how functions related to a pipe are index by that pipe.

> "it is still utterly unclear to me as to why the system can put 3840 x 2160 pixels into a single stream but it can't put the exact same pixels into four 1920 x 1080 pixel sized multiple streams"

Because the multiple streams would need one pipe each. It's not possible to use a single pipe to produce multiple streams, as **stream consist of more than just pixels, and the pipe logic is there to insert the additional markers**.

And this question adds the additional complication of using a single cable for multiple streams.

You can read up on all the gory details for this in the [VESA Display Port Specification 1.2](https://archive.org/details/DP1.2), section 2.6. Figure 2-61 shows how several streams need to be muxed; the "data capture" part would be connected to a digital port, which in turn would be connected to a pipeline.

So it's not possible to just take a single stream and declare it to be multiple streams.

But you already do have this restriction (number of pipes determines maximum number of different "views") for different physical outputs, no matter if they are analog VGA, DVI, HDMI, USB-C alt mode, or whatever.

Comment: It's certainly possible for a single pipe to drive multiple displays, which is what happens with daisy-chaining. The poster's question is why the exact same number of pixels can be displayed in some monitor configurations but not in others, with the same number of execution units. Because of a lack of documentation I can only raise my own theory in a comment below my answer.

Comment: "The poster's question is why the exact same number of pixels can be displayed in some monitor configurations but not in others," It isn't. At least I can't see it in the question. The answer to that is "there are timing restrictions on the pipes, as mentioned in my answer, and at least in some of the earlier Intel GPUs different pipes can have different timing restrictions".

Comment: He says in a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1551543/what-resources-causes-the-number-of-displays-limitation#comment2362450_1552562): "it is still utterly unclear to me as to why the system can put 3840 x 2160 pixels into a single stream but it can't put the exact same pixels into four 1920 x 1080 pixel sized multiple streams". It seems to me that your explanation conflicts with these observations, since it postulates hardware timing concerns that are identical in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons are much simpler than the ones you listed :
Three inbuilt display units instead of two.
Ice Lake also benefited from the high bandwidth offered by
[DisplayPort 1.4a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#1.4a)
and the 'visually lossless' compression offered by VESA's
[Display Stream Compression (DSC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Display_Stream_Compression)
enabling 5K@120Hz.

From the
[10th Gen Intel® Core™ Processor Families Datasheet, Vol. 1](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/10th-gen-core-families-datasheet-vol-1-datasheet.pdf)
comes this diagram on page 92:

**Ice Lake architecture**
[image]

Comparing it with the
[8th and 9th Generation Intel® Core™ Processor Families Datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/8th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.pdf):

**Pre-Ice Lake architecture**

[image]

It can be seen Ice Lake has three display pipes, while the previous generation
had two encode and two decode units. Ice Lake was truly an innovative
architecture for Intel.

---

To achieve this power requires an increase of compute power in both the number
of units and clock speed.

Compare in Wikipedia
[Intel Graphics Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology)
the following characteristics:

[**Kaby Lake Refresh / Amber Lake / Coffee Lake / Whiskey Lake / Comet Lake**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology#Kaby_Lake_Refresh_/_Amber_Lake_/_Coffee_Lake_/_Whiskey_Lake_/_Comet_Lake)

[image]

[**Ice Lake**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology#Ice_Lake)

[image]

See also:
[Intel 'Ice Lake' Gen 11 iGPU will support DisplayPort 1.4a and Display Stream Compression for 5K@120Hz](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Ice-Lake-Gen-11-iGPU-will-support-DisplayPort-1-4a-and-Display-Stream-Compression-for-5K-120Hz.336622.0.html).

Comment: This basically rewords the question as to "what are display pipes? transcoders?" and this [Intel PDF](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/intel-gfx-prm-osrc-skl-vol12-display.pdf) sure has brief explanations but it is still utterly unclear to me as to why the system can put 3840 x 2160 pixels into a single stream but it can't put the _exact same_ pixels into four 1920 x 1080 pixel sized multiple streams...

Comment: That's a question that arises a lot and that the documentation doesn't cover. My own (invented) theory is that the display unit does not manage a pool of pixels, but rather a memory array/table of a certain height+width that has strict allocation rules, where the rectangles of the four streams must fit into it either horizontally or vertically. The display driver will reduce the resolutions to make them fit in. I have seen this theory of mine account for several such posts here. Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation to support/disprove it.

Comment: There's actually documentation that covers it (see my answer). You can also find it used in the open-source Linux drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Each GPU is going to have a unique implementation but I think the resource you are talking about is called a [RAMDAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAMDAC). It looks like most "legacy" display adapters had two RAMDACs in their display controller and could support two displays. Since then there have been newer advancements that don't need a Digital to Analog converter. The example I will give is the AMD [Eyefinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Eyefinity). It only works with DisplayPort because DisplayPort doesn't support analog signals (All digital). This allows them to get away from the legacy RAMDAC and use a new display controller that can handle six displays with one chip.

The Intel "Display Pipe" is likely a type of display controller which contains a legacy RAMDAC for compatibility reasons. Instead of developing their own "modern" all digital display controller, when they need more displays they often just include a discrete NVIDIA\AMD GPU to add additional displays to their systems.

Comment: Note that a single Pipe can connect to different connectors. Most of those are digital today; only a VGA connector has a DAC (digital analog converter). So, no, RAMDACs are not the limiting resource. (I do not know out of my head if there's a palette mechanism similar to RAMDAC for the digital outputs.)

Comment: Intel display controllers support VGA connectors. That is the "compatibility reasons" I cited. Thus they are limited by the old VGA RAMDAC technology in the pipe. So it's rather because of your observation rather than in spite of it.

Comment: Please do read the documentation provided in the other answer. In particular, read up how a palette per pipeline replaces the "RAMDAC" in the G35 (where you already don't need a DAC if using an SDVO), and what happened to this in later interations with gamma and HDR.